# TypeError: string indices must be numbers, not object (Python)

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a long calculation calculator ( does long division, addition etc.) while in the long division section I'm trying to get the number to divide with but I can't (as in numdiv)

Ex: In 240 / 12, the number I'm trying to find is 24, then I'll have another loop that will add 12 to find 2 (as in 24/12 is 2).

Here is my code:

```
##############
#number is bigger (or equal) to number 2

number = 19000
operation = '/'
number2 = 12

##############

import math

longer = len(str(number))
shorter = len(str(number2))
if operation == '/':
    print str(number2) + '/' + str(number)
for i in range(longer - 1):
    if int(str(number)[0, i]) >= number2:
        numdiv = int(str(number)[0, i])
for i in range(1, math.trunc(numdiv / number2)):
    if number2 * (i + 1) >= numdiv:
        print (shorter + 1) * ' ' + number * i
```

The error is 5 lines from the end where I did

```
if int(str(number)[0, i]) >= number2:
```

It said

```
TypeError: string indices must be numbers, not object
```

NEW

I tried doing

```
if str(number)[:i] >= number2:
        numdiv = str(number)[:i]
for i in range(1, math.trunc(numdiv / number2)):
    if number2 * (i + 1) >= numdiv:
        print (shorter + 1) * ' ' + number * i
```

numdiv in this case is trying to be an integer and doing this causes the problem:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: The first thing I notice is you should be using ```[0:i]``` to represent a range of indices, not [0, i].  Still, when I replicated it I got that it "not tuple" instead of "not object"...

Comment: You're not indexing into the string properly. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but indexing formatting is [start:stop:step], right now it thinks you're trying to index with a list, hence the error.

Comment: This [tutorial](http://pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/) should give you a good idea of how to slice strings and what can be done with slices.

Comment: ok, kinda forgot that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With `somestring[0, i]` you are trying to index into a string using a tuple.

Proof:

```
>>> class mystr(str):
...     def __getitem__(self, x):
...         print(x, type(x))
... 
>>> f = mystr('foo')
>>> f[0, 1]
((0, 1), <type 'tuple'>)
```

Trying to index into a string using anything but integers will give you a `TypeError`.

If you want a slice from your string up to position `i`, use

```
str(number)[0:i]
```

or just

```
str(number)[:i]
```

which does the same.